# Discord Bot framework crashes on startup (Python)

Tags: python, discord, bots

been trying to follow a tutorial on a discord bot and every where I've seen the starting framework looks like this:

```
from imports import *

#link to manage bot

#establishes client for bot
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

#create first event, readies the bot for use

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot ready to go")

#run bot from token, DO NOT SHARE TOKEN
client.run(token)
```

But when I run it, it immediately crashes. The token is in and correct, I did pip install discord.py, and have `import discord` and
`from discord.ext import commands` both in as well. The bot is all in my server on Discord It just won't appear online. Please help!

Comment: What did you mean by `crashes`? Do you get any error or app that just immediately exists?

Comment: @KiraLT as soon as I execute opens and then just immediately exits. I can't tell what the error it is throwing if any. I tried doing `input()` but it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps and report if you get any crashes or errors.

- If you haven't already, install C++ build tools, as they are required for discord.py.
- Run `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py` in command prompt (Note this is for windows, if you are using a different OS then you can check the correct install command [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html))
- import `discord` in command prompt just to check it's installed correctly.
- Make sure you've invited your bot to your server.

After you've done those two steps, run this piece of code that I've written, and don't mix up your client secret and your bot token (I've seen it happen a lot).

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
token = "ENTER-TOKEN-HERE"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot ready to go")


client.run(token)
```

Comment: So I did the pip install again to make sure it worked and it did, but when i import discord in cmd I get a modulenotfounderror? Even though when it's imported in the code editor I'm able to execute. I double checked my token is for the bot as well making sure it is in the server. I ran the code you got and have the same problem where it just closes upon running.

Comment: I think I am missing c++ build tools, when I look it up to install it's all for visual studio. Is there a way to install it without VS since I'm using just VScode?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to screen record while attempting to run the program and apparently there was a `ClientConnectorCertificateError` so I found a place to download the certificate: https://crt.sh/?id=2835394 (download in left column down low) and then [add it in chrome](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome)